# Observable string becomes an array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this rxjs code:

```
 private getString(): Observable<string> {
    return from(randomString());
  }

 private transformString(text: string): Observable<string> {
    let newString = text.split("").reverse().join("");
    console.log(newString); <--- all looking good, getting a single string
    return from(newString);
  }

  public getString(): Observable<any> {
    return this.randomString().pipe(
      switchMap((myString) => this.transformString(myString))
    );
  }
```

However there is an issue when I am when receiving the final result in subscription, it is producing a string array of my new string

```
getString().subscribe(str => {
    console.log(str)  <--- prints an array but I am expecting to get just one single reversed string
});
```

Can you explain why it is happens and how to fix?

Comment: What if you do `return of(newString)`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky done, that - same, but if I do `of("abc")` - works but if I do `of(text.split("").reverse().join(""))` does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`from`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) doesn't interpret the argument to create an observable as you'd expect.

Specifically, note the explanation from the linked documentation:

> A String, in this context, is treated as an array of characters.

If you want to get your snippet working using `from` specfically, you'll need to enclose the argument with square brackets. That is:

```
return from([newString]);
```

And below is just a demo of the difference between `from` and `of` usage:

```js
const { from, of } = rxjs;

// 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'
from('hello').subscribe(console.log);

// 'hello'
of('hello').subscribe(console.log);

// 'hello'
from(['hello']).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the string has to be returned as an Observable, using the [of](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) method of the Observable class should work

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

return Observable.of(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of with the rxjs operators, it will emit the transformed value as an observable. So there is no need to create an observable explicitly for the transformed value.

Kindly change the transformString function as below if your intent is to get the transformed string on subscribing it.

```
private transformString(text: string): string {
    let newString = text.split("").reverse().join("");
    console.log(newString);
    return newString;
}
```